# Regex and taking care of possible whitespace

Tags: c#, regex

I need help with my regex expression. I am trying to match keyword `this` but only when it is in parenthesis `(this)`. So far I have:

```
(\()\bthis\b(\))
```

But looks like it also matches the parenthesis wrapping the word, while I only need to grab the word itself. Another issue is that it won't work if there are whitespaces inside the parenthesis: `( this )`

Comment: Remove `\b`, it is useless here. Well, I do not understand why you want to capture a known subpattern. It is [`@"\(\s*(this)\s*\)"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c\(%5cs*\(this\)%5cs*%5c\)&i=\(+this+\)%0d%0a\(this\)%0d%0a\(+this\)%0d%0a\(this+\)).

Comment: What is you final goal? And maybe the entire regex? Looks like what you ask about is different from what you really have. Why did you use word boundaries at all?

Comment: I am still learning. Thanks for downvoting. have a nice day

Comment: 1) never assume you know who downvoted you. 2) were are all still learning, being a beginner doesn't mean you shouldn't write clear and precise questions. 3) a downvote is not permanent, by editing, you can earn your rep back. 4) I did not downvoted you.

Comment: I do not see what was unclear about my question. I started a regex, I tired and researched. Did not mange to fix it, so I asked a question clearly stating the problem and desired outcome

Comment: Another alternative to getting the group is to use the preceding and following match groups: `(?<=\(\s*)this(?=\s*\))`

Comment: @ElenaDBA well it is kinda unclear what you want to match and in which conditions, there are some projections to make. But I think in this particular case, you've been downvoted because your question is too simple. It's Regex basics and you could have found the solution in the documentation or through examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about group matching with that kind of REGEXP expression:

```
\((this)\)
```

Also if you want to match when there are white spaces (spaces, tabs, etc.):

```
\(\s*(this)\s*\)
```

Try it out here : [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oP4wU2/2). All the details about each character I'm using in the regex are detailed on that site.

You can retrieve the `this` value matched in the group by code. Please, check out the documentation related to the language you're using for that.